Problemas al crear ambientes en anaconda no me deja seleccionar "R"
Ya instalé R y Rstudio, instalé anaconda navigator, estoy usando M1 mac.
El problema es que al tratar de crear ambientes, no me habilita la casilla R y no me deja cargar librerías, marca muchos errores y ya desistalé/instalé varias veces todos estos programas y sigue sin funcionar. Detro de los errores que me marca en la consola:
~ % conda install -c conda-forge rstudio-desktop
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rstudio-desktop

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


Revisa las versiones disponibles en anaconda:

Installers

linux-64 v2022.12.0
osx-64 v2022.12.0


La arquitectura de tu ordenador es osx-arm64, la cual aún no está soportada por el paquete y canal solicitado. Puedes trabajar con R instalando el paquete r-base y utilizando un IDE genérico
